# . Master file not rendering in asp.net iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, webforms

i created .Master extension file for my asp.net, but when  it runs it shows http error 404. Error description showing in browser "The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension".

Comment: are you trying to directly open your master page?

Comment: you need to create an aspx page with master to open it in browser.

Comment: Thank you for commenting here, i used controller to redirect to .Master file. Also I have the aspx file for the .Master file.